# How to retrieve last three passwords of a user from active directory?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am implementing a Change password screen for the user and there is a requirement that changed password should not be same as last three passwords of a user.Can  i do that in c# using directory entry and directory searcher.

Comment: Active directory is being used for authentication and when a user enters a new password on the change password screen i want to check that it is not same as last three passwords of the same user.Does that make sense

Comment: Oh I missed your tag, I thought you meant like a physical directory derp...

Comment: Doesn't the password policy enforce that(check if you have one), i don't think you would be able to get the password list(its a security risk), let the AD itself validate that

Comment: You **cannot** ever under any circumstances retrieve a password from any subsystem in Windows. No can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Active Directory: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875814.aspx

Unless you store the passwords in a program database you wont be able to see previous passwords in AD. Go the proper approach and use AD for this task.